# Change view position with AutoLayout Mode on but without constraint?

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-6

I'm updating an old app to use auto-layout but there's a lot of aligning of base code some of them to complex to mapping to auto-layout.

I'm dealing with making an anchor point and them align them relative to the anchor but its not working, I can't even move an element with auto-layout on, there's a work around to my problem? any technique or something to face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No. Can you explain your exact problem, like what you are trying to achieve.

Auto-Layout is something that you use to have convenience of laying out your views instead of you calculating the springs and structs.

Either adopt AutoLayout or perish!

Always try to follow the new Apple standards like your ten commandments, they invest in the API to ease our workflow.